# Теоретический вопрос по передаче данных через API

Tags: json, api

Есть сервер, который читает директорию, и отдает данные в виде списка [file1, file2, ...], имена файлов имеют формат YYYY-MM-DD__HH-MM-SS__name.txt

Эти данные я забираю на фронтенде и вывожу список.

Вопрос в следующем, как более правильно сделать, если я хочу выводить на фронтенде таблицу с колонками Дата | Время | Наименование?

1. Отдавать с сервера JSON в виде [{id, date, time, name}, ...] (это не json но суть понятна ), и выводить на клиенте (item.id, item.date, ...)
2. Просто распарсить на клиенте приходящую строку через split('__')

Примерно представляю что клиент будет заниматься совсем не нужным ему парсингом строки, и если таких строк много, то на клиенте это делать не стоит..

Comment: Может быть ответ может дан при большем количестве входных данных вопроса: какие клиенты (толстые, тонкие); какие требования к безопасности, скорости передачи данных и пр.?

Comment: Клиенты толстые, скорость - локальная сеть, требований к безопасности - нет.

Comment: А чем вам собственно `json` не нравится в качестве формата передачи?

Comment: @CrazyElf Всем нравится, тут вопрос скорее практичности, дописать на сервере отдачу данных в json формате, либо обрабатывать плоский массив на клиенте. Но склоняюсь к 1 варианту в моем вопросе как к более правильному (отдавать с сервера json а не плоский массив)

Comment: @pgs Стандартный формат всегда лучше нестандартного. И тестировать проще и готовые библиотеки для обработки есть. А парсить строки вручную - это кустарщина, не надо такого.

Comment: @CrazyElf Полностью с вами согласен, нужно было мнение со стороны, я его услышал, спасибо большое =)

Comment: `id, date, time, name` - это же вылитый CSV!

Comment: _хочу выводить на фронтенде_ - а бэкенд должен знать о хотелках фронтенда? Представьте, что подключился другой клиент и хочет выводить данные в другом виде - будете подстраивать бэкенд под него?